# If $P(A) = 1/3, P(B|A) = 3/5$, then $A$ and $B$ cannot be disjoint

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

> Show that if $P(A) = 1/3, P(B|A) = 3/5$, then $A$ and $B$ cannot be
>   disjoint

The expression $P(B|A) = 3/5$ means that, given that $A$ happened, the probability of $B$ happening is $3/5$. However, it does not force $B$ to have or not a relation to $A$.

What I know to be a universal rule is:

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A|B) P(B)$$
When $A$ is independent from $B$, we have $P(A|B) = P(A)$. So in the two cases: they're dependent or not dependent, their product isn't $0$, right? So $A$ and $B$ cannot be disjoint.

Even though I understand this proof, I cannot understand why this is true. Suppose that the probability of an event $A$ is $1/3$, and of the event $B$ is $3/5$, as stated in the question. Why cannot $A$ and $B$ be disjoint? $P(A\cap B)$ is just the probability that $A$ and $B$ occur together, right? Why this isn't possible?

Comment: Try instead $P(B\cap A) = P(B\mid A)P(A)$.

Comment: Do you really mean "disjoint", or do you mean "independent"? Because "disjoint" means "can never happen simultaneously", which automatically makes the conditional probability $0$. $P(B\mid A)=3/5$ disproves that by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are defined as sets. So $A,B$ are disjoint events/sets, then we know that $A\cap B = \varnothing$ And from the probability axiom, we could deduce that $\mathbb P(\varnothing) = 0$

Now $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(B|A)\cdot \mathbb P(A) \ne 0$, this suffice to prove $A\cap B \ne \varnothing$